# Публикация в Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Я выложил свое приложение в гугл плей, его опубликовали. Со своего телефона я в плей маркете вводя в поиск название своего приложения нахожу его в первой десятке. Но с любого другого устройства если ввести в поиск тоже самое(название приложения), то в результатах поиска его нет вообще. Я просмотрел вообще все результаты поиска несколько раз - его там нет. Но если ввести после названия приложения имя разработчика, то оно появляется в списке результатов на второй строчке. 
После публикации прошло больше 24 часов.
Почему так происходит? В чем может быть причина того, что приложение вообще не появляется в поиске по его точному названию?

Comment: Думаю лучше обратиться к службе поддержки Google Play

Comment: По опыту, так бывает и поддержка ничего не изменит. Оно будет показываться не всем и не всегда, особенно по началу. Чтобы попадать в список результатов, им должны начать пользоваться. Чтобы попасть в топ да еще и сразу после публикации, его должны установить очень много людей.